# jQuery - How to make the input values ("email", "password") reappear when out of focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click inside the input fields the values "Email" and "password" disappear which is what I want. But if the user doesn't enter his email/pass and clicks somewhere else, I want "Email" and "Password" to reappear.

jQuery:

```
$('.login-user, .login-pass').focus(function() {
    $(this).val("");
  });
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="Email" tabindex="1" class="login-user" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="Password" tabindex="2" class="login-pass" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic, but it would drive me **nuts** if my username disappeared every time I focussed the field. What if I just want to correct a simple typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

I finally got around to doing a [dead-simple plugin](http://code.google.com/p/place5/) for supporting the [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) on browsers that don't do it natively. Been planning to for a long time, and I have a project that needs it, so... `place5` (the plugin) auto-detects native support and leaves things alone (by default) on browsers that can do the job themselves (although you can override that if you really want to use the plugin instead).

---

**Original answer**:

I'd probably do it as a plug-in I could reuse, but basically, since you're dealing only with `input`elements, it can be quite simple:

```
$(".login-user, .login-pass").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .focus(function() {
            if (this.value.length === this.defaultValue) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        })
        .blur(function() {
            if (this.value.length === 0) {
                this.value = this.defaultValue;
            }
        });
});
```

That uses the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157) of the `input` element to set the `value` if the value is blank when the user leaves the field, and to clear the value when the user enters the field if it's the default value. This assumes you use `value="placeholder to show"` in your markup.

A more thorough solution would use the [new `placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) and use [feature-detection](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-placeholder) to see whether it was supported (which it sadly isn't in IE, and even in Firefox 3.6 but I bet 4.0 has it). I keep meaning to do something up...

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.login-user').blur(function() {
        if(this.value.length == 0)
          {
             this.value = "Username"
          }
      });
```

This might be able to be improved, if so please let me know.

Comment: Repeatedly calling `$(this)` is an anti-pattern. Granted only doing it twice isn't *too* bad, but remember that every time you call `$()`, there are several function calls and a memory allocation.

Comment: @TJ, that is good to know. Care to help me rewrite this properly?

Comment: Just cache the `$(this)` to a variable and reuse it. I'd also strongly recommend using braces with `if` statements, but that's style (if you don't, at least put the body on the same line or indent it). But actually, these are just `input` elements, no need for jQuery to set their value, it's not complicated as it is with some other controls. Just `this.value = ...` is fine.

Comment: @TJ, I was thinking that's what you meant, i'll start doing that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider doing this better, even using `placeholder` attribute, but...

```
$('.login-user, .login-pass').each(function() {

    var input = $(this);

    input.focus(function() {

        if ($.trim(input.val()) != this.defaultValue) {
            return;
        }

        input.val('');
    });

    input.blur(function() {

        if ($.trim(input.val()) != '') {
            return;
        }

        input.val(this.defaultValue);
    });

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UxMD3/).

...will fix the issue you are having.

Comment: +1 but as with @Nick's answer, all those `$(this)` repetitions... (And you really don't need jQuery to set the value of an `input` element; just use `this.value`.)

Answer (score 2):

Complete solution which resolves most of the problems of your task:

```
$('.login-user, .login-pass').focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('defaultValue') || $this.data('defaultValue') == $this.val()) {
        if (!$this.data('defaultValue')) {
            $this.data('defaultValue', $this.val());
        }
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length === 0) {
        $this.val($this.data('defaultValue'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use title attributes for default values, then with a little plugin you can achieve what you want.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="Email" tabindex="1" class="login-user" title="Email" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="Password" tabindex="2" class="login-pass" title="Password" />
```

JavaScript

```
(function(a){a.fn.extend({defaultVal:function(){return this.each(function(){var c;var b=a(this);c=b.attr("title");if(b.val()==""){b.val(c)}b.attr("title","");b.focus(function(){var d=a(this);if(d.val()==c){d.val("")}}).blur(function(){var d=a(this);if(d.val()==""){d.val(c)}})})}})})(jQuery);

$('.login-user,.login-pass').defaultVal();
```

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/4wXRa/) is live example

Here decompressed version of my little defaultVal plugin (for learning purposes) ;)

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    defaultVal: function () {
      return this.each(function () {
        var defaultValue;
        var $this = $(this);
        defaultValue = $this.attr("title");
        if ($this.val() == "") {
          $this.val(defaultValue);
        }
        $this.attr("title", "");
        $this.focus(function () {
          var $that = $(this);
          if ($that.val() == defaultValue) {
            $that.val("");
          }
        }).blur(function () {
          var $that = $(this);
          if ($that.val() == "") {
            $that.val(defaultValue);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Who needs linebreaks? Linebreaks are for wusses. ;-)

Comment: Look T.J. I added linebreaks too. ;)